# Need help to release Git from Pycharm override

Tags: python, github, pycharm

It seems that Pycharm as overriden my Git somehow.

When I go to git commit now from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
pycharm -wl1: pycharm: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'pycharm -wl1'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
Steve:repo_test Steve$ git commit
pycharm -wl1: pycharm: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'pycharm -wl1'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I am on a Mac and I deleted the PyCharm app.

This error may stem from a time when I tried out PyCharm's Git integration, which I quickly disabled after trying.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to use pycharm to edit the commit message. Look for git config settings regarding your editor. In the immediate short term (e.g. if you need to get your commit made right now), pass a commit message on the command line with the `-m` flag.

Comment: I will look into the git config settings. I also just tried this command as explained here (https://gist.github.com/denji/9731967) to fully uninstall PyCharm and it reduced the error to `pycharm -wl1: pycharm: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'pycharm -wl1'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.`

Comment: Maybe PyCharm left a [git hook](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) behind? Have a look in `.git/hooks/` within your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Blckknght for the insight to check the git config settings. I did a git config --list and found:

```
core.editor=pycharm -wl1
```

Uninstalling PyCharm or disabling the GitHub integration does not appear to change this back to default.

Remove reference to pycharm and replace with your favorite editor.